# How to Use subheader/subtitle in TYPO3 Content Elements

Tags: subtitle, typo3-6.2.x

How can I use the subheader or subtitle field in the content-element in the backend of TYPO3?

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 offers you to use the field called subheader in your backend. To force TYPO3 to show this field set the following code line in your extention » ext_tables.php within the php-tags.

be aware you flush the backend cache and open the content-element again.

```
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('tt_content', 'subheader', '', 'after:header');
```

after:header tells the TCA where to show it in the backend -> content element.